# SQL counting values of zero?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that will display the total number of transactions attributed to all employees and even the employees with a value of 0.  So far I have managed to do all this but won't show the employees with the amount of zero. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
SELECT
  fss_Employee.empname,
  fss_Employee.empnin,
  COUNT(fss_Employee.empname) AS 'TOTAL TRANSACTIONS'
FROM
  fss_Payment
RIGHT JOIN
  fss_Employee ON fss_Payment.empnin = fss_Employee.empnin
GROUP BY
  fss_Employee.empname
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... How come? It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Use `COUNT(fss_Payment.empname)` instead of `COUNT(fss_Employee.empname)`

Comment: What was that edit about??

Comment: OP's edit that obliterated the question with spam of `SQLSQLSQL` has been rolled back by me, especially considering an answer has also been accepted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they can't I don't think. They have an answer. Bob, stop with the nonsense though, you're going the right way for a suspension. The multiple rollbacks will have flagged a mod.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT e.empname, e.empnin,
       COUNT(p.empnin) AS TOTAL_TRANSACTIONS
FROM fss_Employee e LEFT JOIN
     fss_Payment p
     ON p.empnin = e.empnin
GROUP BY e.empname, e.empnin;
```

Comment: That works, but have you an idea how I could get this to display the employees also with NULL values, null values are included in the employee table but not the payment table?

Comment: `COALESCE(COUNT(p.empnin),0) AS TOTAL_TRANSACTIONS` will show 0 instead of NULL

Comment: @Stavr00 . . . `COUNT()` never returns `0`, so the `COALESCE()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bob . . . This returns all employees . . . with one row per unique combination of `empname`/`empnin`.